# How to combine binary and unary function to obtain the step function for a fold?

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, pointfree

When reading [Chapter 4 from Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html), I solved the exercise 1, at page 97, with the following lines

```
asInt :: String -> Int
asInt ('-':x) = asInt x
asInt xs = foldl (\a x -> a*10 + digitToInt x) 0 xs
```

then I have checked some comments from the linked page, and verified that this is a solution adopted by the majority.

On the other hand, I think it would be nice to write the function not as a lambda (`\a x -> a*10 + digitToInt x`), which is so verbose and gives names to parameters (`a` and `x`) which really need not be given one, but as the "combination" of other functions, namely the binary functions `(*)`, `(+)`, and the unary function `digitToInt`; however I can't figure out how to combine those three in a binary function equivalent to the lambda above.

I think the ingredients to compose are `(*10)`, the unary function that has to act on `foldl`'s accumulator, `digitToInt`, the unary function that acts on the element of the list `xs`, and `(+)`, that has to combine these two.

Comment: See http://pointfree.io It should come up with `(.digitToInt).(+).(*10)`

Comment: Pointfree code is often a case of "just because you can doesn't mean you should". It's most useful when you have a long chain of functions with an obvious input-output pipeline. But when you start doing sections with the `(.)` operator to get things in the right places, remember that variable names were invented for a reason.

Comment: @FrownyFrog, thank you for letting me know about this Pointfree.io site! However, it'd be nice if you could write your own answer where you explain how that function composition work.

Comment: The fact that you do not need an explanation for `\a x -> a*10 + digitToInt x` but you do for `(.digitToInt).(+).(*10)` is a massive hint about which code to use. Point-free style can be very beautiful in many cases, but in others it quickly degenerates into obfuscation, deserving the name of point-less style. Distinguishing between the two is quite important to produce quality code.

Comment: I see your point, @chi; however, I'm still eager to understand how the pointless-style function works in this case; not necessarily because I will use it, as I cannot deny it obfuscates the meaning of the function (at least in this  case), but because I think there's something I can learn from it, whereas there's nothing a lambda can teach but the syntax.

Comment: Another pointfree version of the function (which I don't recommend) would be `curry $ uncurry (+) . bimap (*10) digitToInt` using `bimap` from `Data.Bifunctor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(you wanted to understand how the pointless-style functions work here, so here it is.)*

First.

```
(\a x -> a*10 + digitToInt x)
= 
(\a x -> (+) ((*10) a) (digitToInt x))
= 
(curry $ (+) . (*10) . fst <*> digitToInt . snd)
=
(curry $ uncurry (+) . ((*10) *** digitToInt))
```

Second.

```
(\a x -> a*10 + digitToInt x)
= 
(\a x -> (+) ((*10) a) (digitToInt x))
= 
(\a x -> ((+) . (*10)) a . digitToInt $ x)
= 
(\a   -> ((+) . (*10)) a . digitToInt    )
= 
(\a   -> (. digitToInt) ( ((+) . (*10)) a ) )
= 
(\a   -> (. digitToInt) . ((+) . (*10)) $ a )
= 
         (. digitToInt) .  (+) . (*10)
```

### How does it work

First.

```
(curry $ (+) . (*10) . fst <*> digitToInt . snd)  a  x
= {-  curry f a b  =  f (a, b)                               -}
        ((+) . (*10) . fst <*> digitToInt . snd) (a, x)
= {-  (f <*> g) a  =  f a (g a)   ;   (f . g) a  =  f (g a)  -}
   ((+) . (*10)) (fst (a, x)) (digitToInt ( snd  (a, x)))
=
   ((+) . (*10))       a      (digitToInt            x  )
= {-  (f . g) a  =  f (g a)   ;   (`c` b) a  =  (a `c` b)    -}
    (+)   (a*10)              (digitToInt            x  )
= {-  (c) a b  =  (a `c` b)                                  -}
          (a*10)            +  digitToInt            x
```

and,

```
(curry $ uncurry (+) . ((*10) *** digitToInt))  a  x
= {-  curry f a b  =  f (a, b)                -}
        (uncurry (+) . ((*10) *** digitToInt)) (a, x)
= {-  (f *** g) a  =  (f $ fst a, g $ snd a)  -}
         uncurry (+) (  (*10) a , digitToInt       x )
= {-  uncurry f (a, b)  =  f a b              -}
                 (+) (  (*10) a) (digitToInt       x )
= {-  (`c` b) a  =  (a `c` b)                 -}
                 (+)   (a*10)    (digitToInt       x )
= {-  (c) a b  =  (a `c` b)                   -}
                       (a*10)  +  digitToInt       x
```

Second.

```
           ((. digitToInt) . (+) . (*10)) a x
= {-  (f . g) a  =  f (g a)     -}
           ((. digitToInt) . (+)) ((*10) a) x
= {-  (`c` b) a  =  (a `c` b)   -}
           ((. digitToInt) . (+)) (a*10)    x
= {-  (f . g) a  =  f (g a)     -}
            (. digitToInt) ( (+)  (a*10) )  x
= {-  (`c` b) a  =  (a `c` b)   -}
 ((+) (a*10) . digitToInt)                  x
= {-  (f . g) a  =  f (g a)     -}
  (+) (a*10) ( digitToInt                   x )
= {-  (c) a b  =  (a `c` b)     -}
      (a*10) + digitToInt                   x
```

Another possibility is *partially* point-free,

```
foldl  (\a -> (a*10 +) . digitToInt)  ...
```

which is shorter than the full lambda yet still more readable than all the fully point-free versions.

Comment: The two chunks labelled "second" are an the answer for me, so I will accept it; however I'd add some text to make the answer more readable for the future reader who could skip the comments where `curry` and `uncurry` are mentioned; furthermore, some words/links about `<*>` and `***` would be appreciated (I've only seen `*` used as the multiplication symbol and by the output of `:kind` to display concrete types.

Comment: will review your edit shorty; note it's not `*` but [`<*>`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-) -- the "apply" method of the `Applicative` type class. will also add the hackage [links](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-42--42--42-) to the answer later. thanks.

Comment: Hi, I *like* the parens around the lambdas, I think they help the clarity. that's just my opinion. :) So I'd rather keep'em.

Comment: the Applicative and the Arrow are *general*, abstract type classes, but used with functions, their `<*>` and `***` are *nothing more* than the definitions which I already include in the answer, `(f <*> g) a = (f a) (g a)` and `(f *** g) a = (f $ fst a, g $ snd a)`. So I just use the two operators as point-free combinators.

Answer (score 4):

It's simpler to reduce if you convert each digit to an integer *before* calling `foldl`:

```
asInt xs = foldl (\a x -> a*10 + x) 0 (map digitToInt xs)
    -- == foldl ((+) . (10 *)) 0 (map digitToInt xs)
```

which you can further eta-convert to

```
asInt = foldl ((+) . (10 *)) 0 . map digitToInt
```

(I believe that the intermediate list that would otherwise be produced by `map` is not created, due to list fusion. The output of each call to `digitToInt` is used immediately by `foldl`, rather than placed into a list.)

Comment: Does your statement about list fusion change depending on whether `foldl` or `foldl'` is used?

Comment: I don't think so, though my understanding of list fusion is shaky. Assuming that `foldl` does benefit from list fusion, I don't think it matters if the item comes from the penultimate argument to `foldl` or from the first element of the input list.